# switching bulb socket with larger socket

Tags: light-fixture, replacement

I have a Harbor Breeze  #40948,040949 ceiling fan. It comes with candelabra bulbs. Can I switch the bulb socket from another fan so, I can use regular bulbs in it?

Comment: You may not need to. Candelabra bulbs are readily available in CFL, LED, or whatever tech you want. And unlike weirder sizes like E17, Candelabras are priced about the same as E26.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that first.